# How to use the "is" keyword in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I was looking into [this link](https://www.sach.codes/c%23/wpf/mvvm/collectionview/filtering/2019/12/19/Filter-Data-Using-CollectionView.html) recently and wanted to try it in my test app which uses old .net framework.

How do I convert the below code to make it .Net 4.5 compatibale ?

```
public bool OnFilterTriggered(object item)
{
    if (item is Contact contact)
    {
        var bFrom = int.TryParse(TbFrom, out int from);
        var bTo = int.TryParse(TbTo, out int to);
        if (bFrom && bTo)
            return (contact.Age >= from && contact.Age <= to);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Both TbFrom & TbTo are strings.

I could not find anything helpful regarding this on the internet. Is it even doable ?

Comment: `is` is part of the C# version, which is mostly separate from the target framework version. The equivalent would be `var contact = item as Contact; if (contact != null)`

Comment: It's actually the [pattern matching part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) that's incompatible with 4.5

Comment: @Charlieface Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @orhtej2 No, it's dependent on the C# version, not the target framework version

Comment: @Charlieface I'm actually using Sharpdevelop and yeah I know it has been discontinued ... anyways I've managed to build the code successfully and here is the code (https://codeshare.io/zyYN4D). but I'm getting an error `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'filterGridMVVM.Window1' ` when I run the app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public bool OnFilterTriggered(object item)
    {
        var contact = item as Contact;

        if (contact != null)
        {
            
            int from = 0;
            int to = 0;
            
            var bFrom = int.TryParse(TbFrom, out from);
            var bTo = int.TryParse(TbTo, out to);
            if (bFrom && bTo)
                return (contact.Age >= from && contact.Age <= to);
        }
        return true;
    }
```